# Printing unicode character in MASM32 assembly

Tags: assembly, unicode, x86, masm32

I am trying to print a unicode character in MASM32 assembly, but I can't make it work. Here is a reproducible example :

```
.DATA
output      db    "%x Hello",10,0
unicode     DWORD "∟", 0

.DATA?

.CODE
start:
        push offset unicode
        push offset output
        call crt_printf
        
        invoke  ExitProcess, 0

end start
```

Current output :
`40300a Hello`

Expected output :
`∟ Hello`

Answer (score 4):

You're using `%x` to print a number as hex digits, and the number you're passing is an address.  So `0x40300a` is the address of the `unicode` label in your `.data` section.

`%s` should probably work, if it and the output terminal support the same encoding that your editor and assembler used.  It should just copy bytes from the address you pass, until reaching a `0`, so it should Just Work for UTF-8.  But not for UTF-16, if there's a `0` byte somewhere in there.  `%ls` could work if supported, treating the arg as a `wchar_t*` string.

If you wanted to pass a word or dword as a wide-character for `%lc`, you'd `push dword ptr [unicode]`.  Maybe.  In ISO C99 and C++, `%lc` takes an `int` arg, and prints it like it would a `wchar_t[2]` string (I think with the 2nd element being a terminating 0, [if that's what cppreference means](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)).  But Microsoft has persistently declined to support standard C and C++ features, especially around printf, so who knows what `crt_printf` supports.

Comment: Hello, thank for your time. I've tried with ```%s```, ```%ls```, as well as ```%lc```. Sadly I can't make it work, but it is probably coming from what ```crt_printf``` supports as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

The desired character seems to be [└ Box Drawings Light Up and Right](https://unicode-table.com/en/2514/)
which has encoding `0xE29494` in UTF-8 alias `0x1425` in UTF-16LE.
I don't know how did your texteditor encoded the source line `unicode DWORD "∟", 0` but the (unreproducible for me) function `crt_printf` seems to not cope with it.

MS Windows works with UTF-16LE, you'll need WinAPI function [WriteConsoleW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) and define the lpBuffer as

```
    unicode db 14h,25h
    output  dw " ","H","e","l","l","o",10,0
nNumberOfCharsToWrite EQU ($-unicode)/2  ; Number of 16bit characters.
```

Questions related to Microsoft Macro Assembler have a dedicated [MASM Forum here](http://masm32.com/board/index.php).

Printing Unicode strings might be easier in other assemblers, for instance with macro [StdOutput](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/winapi.htm#StdOutput) in €ASM

```
rchg PROGRAM Format=PE,Entry=start
       INCLUDE winapi.htm
[.data]       
Buffer DB 14h,25h
       DU " Hello",10,0
[.text]       
start: StdOutput Buffer,Console=yes,Unicode=yes
       WinAPI ExitProcess, 0
     ENDPROGRAM
```

The previous source compiles and works fine:

```
R:\>euroasm.exe rchg.asm
I0010 EuroAssembler version 20191104 started.
I0020 Current directory is "R:\".
I0180 Assembling source file "rchg.asm".
I0470 Assembling program "Rchg". 
I0510 Assembling program pass 1. 
I0510 Assembling program pass 2. 
I0530 Assembling program pass 3 - final.
I0660 32bit FLAT PE file "Rchg.exe" created, size=16732. 
I0650 Program "Rchg" assembled in 3 passes with errorlevel 0. 
I0750 Source "rchg" (1229 lines) assembled in 2 passes with errorlevel 0.
I0860 Listing file "rchg.asm.lst" created, size=1753.
I0980 Memory allocation 960 KB. 28249 statements assembled in 1 s.
I0990 EuroAssembler terminated with errorlevel 0.

R:\>rchg.exe
└ Hello
```